# How would you send a request with a PFX certificate in Cypress?

Tags: http, request, ssl-certificate, cypress, pfx

Did anyone have success submitting a request in Cypress with a PFX certificate?  If possible, please share.  I experienced unauthorization errors.  Thank you for your help.

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
describe('Submit A Cafe Order Test', () => {

  const endPoint='https://0.0.0.77:9000/spc/api/v1/order/receive';


  it("Standard In-store API Order Test", () => {

    const options = {
      method: 'PUT',
      url: endPoint,
      "pfx": "H:/API_Info/Certificates/spc.device.client.722.pfx",
            "passphrase": password,
      
      body: { 
       .....omitted...

      }
    }

    cy.request(options)
          .then(function(response){
              expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
          });
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there has already been an opened PR (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/15179). We have to hope it's merged soon.

Comment: Btw. We've decided to not use Cypress in the end. As I've sought a solution for Playwright, I've found this workaround - https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1799.
I guess you're trying to log in and using Playwright/puppeteer as a plugin is a common approach.